# javascript break and continue the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, loops, break

How can I pause/break this loop when 'delay' and 'animation' inside it are running and continue it from the break place after 'animation' is done in order to prevent the 'i' variable from being overwritten?
Or maybe there are another ways to prevent the 'i' variable from overwriting during animation?

```
for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
    var now = inputs[i];
    var top = inputs[i].attr('top');
    if(!now.val()){
        if(dialog.css('display')=='none'){
            now.addClass('style');
            dialog.css('top',top).fadeIn(200);
        }
        else {
            dialog.delay(300).animate({"top": top}, 500, function(){
                now.addClass('style');
            });
        } 
    }
    else{
        now.removeClass('style');
    }
}
```

I can't put adding Class before delay and animation as I need to add Class with delay and after animation is done.

Answer (score 3):

by recalling same function till all element animation complete.

```
var i = 0;

function animate() {
   if (inputs.length == i) {
      return;
   }
   var now = inputs[i];
   var top = inputs[i].attr('top');
   if (!now.val()) {
      if (dialog.css('display') == 'none') {
         now.addClass('style');
         dialog.css('top', top).fadeIn(200, function(){
            animate(); // recall it after fadein
         });
      } else {
         dialog.delay(300).animate({
            "top": top
         }, 500, function () {
            now.addClass('style');
            animate();// recall it after animate complete
         });
      }
   } else {
      now.removeClass('style');
   }

   i++;
}
animate();
```